# Regex: match word and number with decimal

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, decimal, match

I would like to match words and numbers and drop all special characters unless it's a period between numbers.

Specifically, I want to have the effect of **`\W+`** except instead of splitting 49.99 into 49 and 99, I want to keep it as 49.99

For example I want

> "millie's math house 3-7 (win/mac) now 49.99 only."

to be split into

> `['millie', 'math', 'house', '3', '7', 'win', 'mac', 'now', '49.99', 'only']`

But right now, using just **`\W+`**, I get

> `['millie', 'math', 'house', '3', '7', 'win', 'mac', 'now', '49', '99', 'only']`

How can I keep words that have periods in the middle, but get rid of special characters otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: Quite late here to post an extensive answer. Just match and use a pattern like this `\d+\.\d+|[^\W\d]+|\d+`. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sZ3tV2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
[^\w.]+
```

Instead of matching all non words characters, it matches everything that isn't a word character/period.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for a fact there will be a decimal every time in the middle, then this is viable:

> (\d+.\d+)

You can check the regular expression here:

[regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding dot character, for example

```
[\W.]+
```

Comment: There is no need to escape a dot in a character class. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xH0fY3)